# Get all window handles and respective label handles given process name

Tags: c#

is it possible to get the handle of a specific component in an unknown number of window opened by the same program?
The program foo.exe contains a button that, when clicked, opens a form containing a Label and an Image ( with no upper bound on the number of forms opened). Is possible to get all the handle of the Label component of every window openend, given the process name "foo" ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

with `EnumWindows` or `FindWindow` you can find the application window depending if you already know the title or the process name or so on, you can even use `FindWindowLike` if you really do not much of it.

Once in one way or another you know the windows handle of your window, with `GetDlgItem` you can get info about your child controls.

Comment: You are going to want EnumChildWindows as well